# check or count selected files less than 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check only 2 files be able to select or upload, and produce alert if it's not 2 files. Here is my code, it's work for more than 2 but not for less than 2.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myfiles').change(function(e){
    const fi = e.target.files;
    if (fi.length < 2 || fi.length > 2) {
      alert('You must select 2 files at a time');
    } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="myfiles" name="myfiles[]" multiple="multiple">
```

How to count file selected less than 2?

Comment: Out of curiosity,  why not fi.length != 2

Comment: @KevinO same result which is not working for less than 2

Comment: It works for me with 1 and 3 files.

Comment: I've just tested your code and it works. Your way or the way @KevinO suggested.

Comment: even alert (fi.length) produce nothing if 1 file selected. only work for 2 or more. what could be the reason?

Comment: @user3613026 - I've just updated your question to include a snippet using the code you originally posted. That code is functioning exactly as expected.

Comment: @fubar sorry my bad, there is 2 more codes checking the file name before check the length that causing the code stop running if 1 file selected.

Comment: @user3613026 - the code you have posted works, so if it's not working the problem lies in other code you've written. Please update your question to include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

code is working fine. Better to use !=2 like below. Make code simple.

```
if (fi.length != 2) {
         alert('You must select 2 files at a time');
      }
```